# 2 email servers for single domain, one for sending and other for receiving

Tags: email, dns

Is it possible to have 2 email servers for domain. One for sending and other for receiving

Let's say I have a domain xyz.com, I set a email server with mx record so that any email destined for domain xyz.com reaches this email server (mx record) and it shouldnt have sending functionality. If I need to have a another email server only to send email on behalf of this domain what record I need to create ? Is it possible or we will use the same server for both sending and reviving emails. Please clarify. This question could be dumb but it could clarify me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You wish for sends from one server, but any error returns to be on the other one? How will you match them together? Seems like an X-Y problem - you should ask about your real problem, not about your own solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as just DNS goes, there is a separation between sending and receiving:

- An **MX** record is just for your "receiving" servers. These servers should all be able to deliver email to @domain.com mailboxes.
- An **SPF** record would list your authorized "sending" servers.
- **DKIM** records involve keys configured on your "sending" servers as well

They don't need to be the same list. It's common to allow another service to send email like newsletters from your domain, but not set them up to receive.

DNS records will not block any functionality, they just help validate.

Comment: So .. Yes? It is possible?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Is what possible? You don't *need* anything in DNS to send email. Just to receive it (MX). SPF will help stop your email going to spam or getting blacklisted, but is not exactly required. Whether or not you can have separate email servers for send/receive would depend more on the service you use

Answer (score -1):

Technically, any machine can send emails.

However, other mail servers may not trust your sending server since they can not verify it is authorized to send emails for your domain.